# Google+ Sign-In flow with JavaScript Not Working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-plus, google-signin

I am implementing google+ signin with javascript with help of nice article [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow) they have provided a working example at

> url https://google-developers.appspot.com/+/demos/signin_demo_trigger

with works well in internet explorer also. But when i copy the source code of same example and try to run it by changing client id , it is working fine in all browser except internet explorer.

here is the source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google+ Sign-in button demo: JavaScript flow</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #signin-button {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #oauth2-results pre {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 600px;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

        .show {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var loginFinished = function (authResult) {
            if (authResult) {
                console.log(authResult);
                var el = document.getElementById('oauth2-results');
                var label = '';
                toggleDiv('oauth2-results');
                if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
                    label = 'User granted access:';
                    gapi.auth.setToken(authResult);
                } else {
                    label = 'Access denied: ' + authResult['error'];
                }
                el.innerHTML =
                    label + '<pre class="prettyprint"><code>' +
                    // JSON.stringify doesn't work in IE8.
                    '{<br />' +
                    '  "id_token" : "' + authResult['id_token'] + '",<br />' +
                    '  "access_token" : "' + authResult['access_token'] + '",<br />' +
                    '  "state" : "' + authResult['state'] + '",<br />' +
                    '  "expires_in" : "' + authResult['expires_in'] + '",<br />' +
                    '  "error" : "' + authResult['error'] + '",<br />' +
                    '  "error_description" : "' + authResult['error_description'] + '",<br />' +
                    '  "authUser" : "' + authResult['authuser'] + '",<br />' +
                    '  "status" : {"' + '<br />' +
                    '    "google_logged_in" : "' + authResult['status']['google_logged_in'] + '",<br />' +
                    '    "method" : "' + authResult['status']['method'] + '",<br />' +
                    '    "signed_in" : "' + authResult['status']['signed_in'] + '"<br />' +
                    '  }<br />' +
                    '}</code></pre>';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('oauth2-results').innerHTML =
                    'Empty authResult';
            }
        };

        function toggleDiv(id) {
            var div = document.getElementById(id);
            if (div.getAttribute('class') == 'hide') {
                div.setAttribute('class', 'show');
            } else {
                div.setAttribute('class', 'hide');
            }
        }
        var options = {
            'callback': loginFinished,
            'approvalprompt': 'force',
            'clientid': '155414628264-enc3584h601s2offmm64n8dg7nlupsd0.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schema.org/CommentAction http://schema.org/ReviewAction',
            'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin'
        };

        function startFlow() {
            toggleDiv('startFlow');
            gapi.auth.signIn(options);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="startFlow">
        <a class="button button-blue" href="javascript:startFlow();">Click me</a>
        to trigger the sign-in flow with
        <a href="/+/web/signin/reference#gapi.auth.signIn"
           target="_parent"><code>gapi.auth.signIn()</code></a>
    </div>
    <div id="oauth2-results" class="hide"></div>
    <div style="font: 12px sans-serif, Arial; margin-left: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em">
        <a href="javascript:document.location.reload();">Reload the example</a> or <a href="/+/demos/signin_demo_trigger" target="_blank">open in a new window</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My local host url is :`https://localhost/index.html`

**please suggest what should I do ? I need java script google login for my application which run in all browser.**